# How to manually activate user in dashboard only by admin

Tags: functions, users, dashboard, user-access, activation

I'm looking for a function that allows admins (only) to activate new users. When a user registers he have to be approved by the admin before he gets access to log in.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: There's no such feature in WordPress itself, so probably you will require some plugin (community one or self-written). +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are using this wordpress plug in - [New User Approve](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/new-user-approve/)

Provides functionality to approve/deny new user registrations.